# SMTP with app-passowrd of O365 does not work

Tags: email, office-365, authentication, smtp, microsoft

I have an email address in Office 365 which I would like to use for a scanner's SMTP feature.

For this email address, I have enforced MFA to be able to set an app-password.

I give the following settings in the scanner:

```
server name: smtp.office365.com
port: 587
username: abcd@domain.com
password: the app password that I made in O365
```

This does not work and give an authentication error.

My clue so far is that it my email address only work with modern authentication, while this scanner smtp feature only work with basic authentication, and if this is indeed the reason, I wonder if I can tell O365 to allow basic authentication only for this email address.

My second question is if there might be any way to test this app-password in a very simple way to make sure it works.